# Add and remove Ektron content items from taxonomies? (C#)

Tags: c#, taxonomy, ektron, content-management

I have content items stored in Ektron that are assigned to taxonomies. I'm trying to create a method that will allow me to programmatically change the taxonomies. So far I find the content item by ID, and I'm able to retrieve its taxonomies, but I'm not sure how to change them.

```
var ektronItem = contentManager.GetItem((long) item.tctmd_id);
if (ektronItem != null) // item exists in Ektron
{
    var newTaxonomies = item.taxonomy_ids;

    var taxonomyAPI = new Taxonomy();
    var taxData = taxonomyAPI.ReadAllAssignedCategory(ektronItem.Id);

    foreach (var tax in taxData)
    {
        taxonomyAPI.RemoveTaxonomyItem(???);
        // here I'm trying to remove the content item from the taxonomy
    }
}
```

taxonomyAPI.RemoveTaxonomyItem() takes a Ektron.Cms.TaxonomyRequest object, but I'm not sure how to create this. I'm also not sure if this is even the method I should be using.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else wants to know how to do this, here's the solution I came up with:

```
var contentManager = new Ektron.Cms.Framework.Content.ContentManager();
var criteria = new Ektron.Cms.Content.ContentCriteria(ContentProperty.Id, EkEnumeration.OrderByDirection.Ascending);
criteria.AddFilter(ContentProperty.FolderId, CriteriaFilterOperator.EqualTo, toUpdate.folder_id);
criteria.OrderByDirection = Ektron.Cms.Common.EkEnumeration.OrderByDirection.Descending;
criteria.OrderByField = Ektron.Cms.Common.ContentProperty.GoLiveDate;
criteria.FolderRecursive = true;
criteria.PagingInfo = new Ektron.Cms.PagingInfo(50, 1);

var ektronItem = contentManager.GetItem((long) item.tctmd_id);
if (ektronItem != null) // item exists in Ektron
{
    // update taxonomy in Ektron
    var taxIds = item.taxonomy_ids;

    var taxonomyAPI = new Taxonomy();
    var taxData = taxonomyAPI.ReadAllAssignedCategory(ektronItem.Id);

    var taxManager = new Ektron.Cms.Framework.Organization.TaxonomyItemManager();

    var taxCriteria = new TaxonomyItemCriteria();
    // create a taxonomy criteria of the item ID
    taxCriteria.AddFilter(TaxonomyItemProperty.ItemId, CriteriaFilterOperator.EqualTo, item.tctmd_id);
    // get all taxonomy items with item ID 
    var taxItems = taxManager.GetList(taxCriteria);
    // determine taxonomyItemType
    var type = taxItems.FirstOrDefault().ItemType;

    foreach (var tax in taxData)
    {                      
        // delete from old taxonomies
        taxManager.Delete(tax.Id, (long)item.tctmd_id, type);
    }

    foreach (var tax in taxIds)
    {
        // add to new taxonomies
        var taxonomyItemData = new TaxonomyItemData()
        {
            TaxonomyId = tax,
            ItemType = type,
            ItemId = (long)item.tctmd_id
        };
        try
        {
            taxManager.Add(taxonomyItemData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am creating a new content in C#. How can I check if a content with the "title" exist so I don't create new content with a subscript at the end of the title?